# How do I create a nested dictionary under a key that is yet to exist?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an empty array.

I want to assign a value like this: `array[key][subkey] = 'value'`

This produces a *KeyError* as array[key] does not exist yet.

What do I do? I tried the following...

```
array['key'] = None
array['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

I tried:

```
array['key'] = []
array['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I tried:

```
array['key'] = ['subkey']
array['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

So what do I do?

Comment: Nested dictionaries you meant?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yes

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), passing the *default factory* as `dict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'key': {'subkey': 'value'}})
```

To apply further levels of nesting, you can create a `defaultdict` that returns `defaultdict`s to a *n-th* depth of nesting, using a function, preferably anonymous, to return the nested default dict(s):

```
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
>>> d['key']['subkey']['subsubkey'] = 'value'
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x104082398>, {'key': defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'subkey': {'subsubkey': 'value'}})})
```

<sub>Example shows nesting up to depth `n=1`</sub>

Comment: The issue with using it is that the last value can't be of type list for example, can you find a solution for that ? d['key']['subkey'].append(msg) will raise AttributeError which need to be handled d['key']['subkey'] = [msg]. can we have dynamic nested with last one as list ?

Comment: @SionC https://godbolt.org/z/K54GMTz4n

Comment: it will only be 2d .. we are looking for nested unlimited.

Comment: @SionC It should be possible to implement a factory class which defines `__call__` that can do that sort of thing.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Answer (score 8):

You are using a `[]` list literal not a `{}` dict literal:

```
array['key'] = {}
array['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
```

But this isn't very useful in a loop.
In a loop you could test if `'key'` is not in `array` - which is a cheap operation (`O(1)` lookup):

```
if 'key' not in array:
    array['key'] = {}
array['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
```

But you can use `setdefault()` to do the same thing and give `key` a default value if it doesn't already have a value, e.g.:

```
array.setdefault('key', {})['subkey'] = 'value'
```

And if this looks ugly, then you can always use [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a nested `defaultdict` like this, goes arbitrarily deep automatically:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def ndd():
        return defaultdict(ndd)

>>> array = ndd()
>>> array['key']['subkey']['subsubkey'] = 'value'
>>> array
defaultdict(<function ndd at 0x041AC270>,
            {'key': defaultdict(<function ndd at 0x041AC270>,
                                {'subkey': defaultdict(<function ndd at 0x041AC270>,
                                                       {'subsubkey': 'value'})})})
```

(I indented the output for readability.)

Originally saw that [from severb](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/14216/tree-solutions-18-20-lines/5).

Comment: The issue with using it is that the last value can't be of type list for example, can you find a solution for that ? array['key']['subkey']['subsubkey'].append(msg) will raise AttributeError which need to be handled  array['key']['subkey']['subsubkey'] = [msg]

Answer (score 3):

I have used this alternative way before (edit: although I preferred Moses Koledoye answer):

```
array = {}

try:
    array[key][subkey] = 'value'
except KeyError:
    array[key] = {}
    array[key][subkey] = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can the below codes be used as a different method?

```
>>> array = {}
>>> array["key"] = {"subkey": "value"}
>>> array
{'key': {'subkey': 'value'}}
>>>
```

Comment: Where I have used it (creating dictionaries inside loops) this is not an option as it does not "fill" the dictionary but rather creates a new one.