# Python: Nested dictionary - create if key doesn't exist, else sum 1

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

**ESCENARIO**
I am trying to count the number of times a word appears in a sentence, for a list of sentences. 
Each sentence is a list of words.
I want the final dictionary to have a key for each word in the entire corpus, and a second key indicating the sentences in which they appear, with the value being the number of times it appears in it.

**CURRENT SOLUTION**
The following code works correctly:

```
dfm = dict()
for i,sentence in enumerate(setences):
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in df.keys():
            dfm[word] = dict()
        if i not in dfm[word].keys():
            dfm[word][i] = 1
        else:
            dfm[word][i] += 1
```

**QUESTION**
Is there any cleaner way to do it with python?
I have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992106/how-do-i-create-a-nested-dictionary-under-a-key-that-is-yet-to-exist) where they suggest using:

```
dic.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

and,

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

I think they are good solution, but I can't figure out how to adapt that to my particular solution.

Thanks !

Comment: use `Counter` ?

Comment: @temmo Collections Counter is normally a good choice but looking at the structure OP wants I think the defaultdict makes more sense.

Comment: Extra comment: Good work on preparing your question and to search for a possible solution before posting here on SO. You deserve a star!

Answer (score 4):

Say you have this input:

```
sentences = [['dog','is','big'],['cat', 'is', 'big'], ['cat', 'is', 'dark']]
```

Your solution:

```
dfm = dict()
for i,sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in dfm.keys():
            dfm[word] = dict()
        if i not in dfm[word].keys():
            dfm[word][i] = 1
        else:
            dfm[word][i] += 1
```

Defaultdict int:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dfm2 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for i,sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for word in sentence:
        dfm2[word][i] += 1
```

Test:

```
dfm2 == dfm  # True


#{'dog': {0: 1},
# 'is': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
# 'big': {0: 1, 1: 1},
# 'cat': {1: 1, 2: 1},
# 'dark': {2: 1}}
```

Comment: This was exactly the answer I had in mind so I took the liberty to change it to compare it to the original solution. Hope that is ok for you @rassar.

Comment: @AntonvBR That's great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for cleaner version use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

string = 'this is america this is america'
x=Counter(string.split())
print(x)
```

output

```
Counter({'this': 2, 'is': 2, 'america': 2})
```

if want some own code then

copying input data (sentence) from @rassar

```
def func(list_:list):      
    dic = {}
    for sub_list in list_:
        for word in sub_list:
            if word not in dic.keys():
                dic.update({word:1})
            else:
                dic[word]+=1
    return dic


sentences = [['dog','is','big'],['cat', 'is', 'big'], ['cat', 'is', 'dark']]


print(func(sentences))
```

output

```
{'dog': 1, 'is': 3, 'big': 2, 'cat': 2, 'dark': 1}
```

Comment: This isn't correct - OP wants a dictionary mapping each word to a dictionary, where the second dictionary maps {sentence number: count of words in that sentence}.

Comment: @rassar also added dict mapping

Comment: I would add a `split()` at the beginning of the function so that we can input something fancy like `sentences = ["dog is big", "cat is dark"]` directly.

Comment: @Guimoute i had added that way you can see that way in previous edits, but Op didn't  gave any input data, so i use rassar input data and modify the code :)

Answer (score 0):

## Use counters

```py
from collections import Counter
    
sentences = ["This is Day", "Never say die", "Chat is a good bot", "Hello World", "Two plus two equals four","A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "Young chef, bring whisky with fifteen hydrogen ice cubes"]

sentenceWords = ( Counter(x.lower() for x in sentence.split()) for sentence in sentences)

#print result
print("\n".join(str(c) for c in sentenceWords))
```