Using Nested Objects in Python with objects named after variable (date)
I'm trying to create a short python script to reformat some JSON from a webdevice and create a new JSON file, eventually to put on a webserver for local access on my network. I'm using some beginner python literature and a bit of goggling and so far I have :
import json
from datetime import date
import requests
import os

#create JSON structure as object names device

currentmonth = date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

device ={} #create empty ojects
month = {}
June24={}
Log_Cabin={}
Monthly_Total={}

month['June24'] = June24
device['Log_Cabin'] = Log_Cabin
Log_Cabin['month'] = month
month['Monthly Total'] = Monthly_Total


#capture JSON from shelly device
url = 'http://192.168.0.241/cm?cmnd=Status%208'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
data = resp.json() 

#assign values to variables
currentenergy = (data['StatusSNS']['ENERGY']['Power'])
totalenergyused = (data['StatusSNS']['ENERGY']['Total'])
filename = date.today().strftime("%B%y") + '.json'
key = date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d") #establish key as todays date
value = currentenergy # establish value as energyvariable
print(value)

try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read() or '{}'
    data = json.loads(contents)
except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError) as e:
    print("Error")

device["Log_Cabin"]["month"]['June24'][key] = value
print(value)
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
        print(json.dumps(device), file=f)

This will create the basic structure on the file and update 1 value in the June24 part of the nested object. I would though like this part of the JSON object to be named dynamically as the month using datetime.

If you have a datetime object, you can use .strftime("%B") to get the month name as a string.

If I understand you want to have key of dictionary which will be month and year. Instead of use key 'June24', use date.today().strftime("%b%y").
But I think much better structure would be
today=date.today()
device["Log_Cabin"]["year"][today.year]["month"][today.month]["day"][today.day] = value


Thanks, it might be an easier way to maintain data that way, however I cannot nest beyond a single entry so I can include only 1 of the today.x entries. If I add 2 I get a key error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992106/how-do-i-create-a-nested-dictionary-under-a-key-that-is-yet-to-exist

When you create dict device replace with device = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
